# Buffering selected objects in the map in Graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, buffer, qgis-modeler

Process: Buffer selected point to 3000m then unselect that point and grab all records from a particular layer that intersect with the buffer.

I can't find a way of specifying that the buffer must use only the selected object in the map. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess a QGIS Model tool doesn't support `Selected features only` option. Instead, use `Extract selected features` tool before `Buffer`.

[image]